# SQL select a decimal column and convert it to an int with leading zeroes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select a decimal column and have it show without the decimal and with leading zeroes.
The column is defined as `vendor_cost(decimal(9,2),null`

```
select vendor_cost from inventory_vendors
```

The result is `vendor_cost = 1.10`
I want the result to show as `vendor_cost = 000000110`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could multiply by 10 and add the leading zeros:

```
select left(replicate('0', 10) + cast(cast(vendor_cost * 100 as int) as varchar(255)), 10)
```

Or, alternatively, use `str()` and replace the leading spaces with zeros:

```
select replace(str(vendor_cost * 100, 10, 0), ' ', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Format()  2012+

```
Select format(vendor_cost *100,'000000000')
```

Returns

```
000000110
```

I should note that Format() has some great features, but it NOT known for its performance